# find a curve for which the segment on the y-axis cut off by any tangent line is equal to the abscissa of the point of tangency.

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

find a curve for which the segment on the y-axis cut off by any tangent line is equal to the abscissa of the point of tangency.

**My Attempt**

Let the point of tangency be $P(a,b)$. Let the angle between the tangent line and the x-axis be $\theta$. Then the $\tan(\theta) = y'$. The tangent line is defined as $(y-a) = y' (x-b)$ making the $x$ and $y$ intercepts:

$$x = \frac{-a}{y'}+b$$
$$y = -by'+a$$

Since the absciessa (x value) is equal to the y-axis cutoff of the point of tangency the following equation must hold:

$$a = -by' + a \rightarrow y= Cx$$

The correct solution is $y = Cx + x\ln(x)$. Where is the error in my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent line at the fixed point $(a, b)$ is in fact $y - b = y’(a)(x - a)$, making the $y$-intercept $b  - ay’(a)$. Setting this intercept equal to the $x$-coordinate we get
$$b - ay’(a) = a.$$
But we should consider a variable point $(x, y)$ on the curve instead of a particular point $(a, b)$. So differential equation now becomes
$$y - xy’ = x,$$ which is first-order linear and has the correct solution.